# HTML checkbox's Status can not be rendered in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            if($("#a").attr("checked")){
                $("#a").attr("checked",false);
            }else{
                $("#a").attr("checked",true);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is my html code :

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="a">
<button>123</button>
```

I click the button on the browser, The checkbox only can switch status on first and second time.

But I do not think the issue of attr(), I have some code before can run Correctly.

```
  $("#delete").click(function(){
        if($("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked")){
            $("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked",false);
        }else{
            $("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked",true);
        }
    });
```

Is there someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like,

```
$("button").click(function () {
   $("#a").prop("checked", !$('#a').prop('checked'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kEEr/)

Comment: But I do not think the issue of attr(), I have some code before can run Correctly.      $("#delete").click(function(){
            if($("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked")){
                $("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked",false);
            }else{
                $("input[name='del_id[]']").attr("checked",true);
            }
        });

Comment: @user2963334 It will work only one time see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/9kEEr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct if you use jQuery Version 1.8.3

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){
            if($("#a").attr("checked")){
                $("#a").attr("checked",false);
            }else{
                $("#a").attr("checked",true);
            }
        })
    })
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YXkgm/1/

If you use above 1.8 use prop

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){
            if($("#a").prop("checked")){
                $("#a").prop("checked",false);
            }else{
                $("#a").prop("checked",true);
            }
        })
    })
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YXkgm/

Comment: @user2963334 change your answer to this